# Problem with a Bilateral Laplace Transform

Tags: laplace-transform, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I was asked to find the Bilateral Laplace Transform of the following distribution
$f(x) = e^{-x^{2}/2}\delta '(2-3x)$.
I simply went on to calculate
\begin{equation*}
\mathcal{L}(f(x))(z) = \langle e^{-x^{2}/2}\delta ' (2-3x) | e^{-zx} \rangle.
\end{equation*}
Then, I took
\begin{equation*}
\langle e^{-x^{2}/2}\delta ' (2-3x) | e^{-zx} \rangle = \langle \delta ' (2-3x) | e^{-x^{2}/2}e^{-zx} \rangle = \langle \delta ' (2-3x) | e^{-zx - x^{2}/2} \rangle.
\end{equation*}
So as to perform a change of variables and apply the Delta centered at zero. The change I took was
\begin{equation*}
-s = 2-3x, \quad \textrm{where} \quad ds = 3dx \quad \textrm{and} \quad x = \frac{2+s}{3}.
\end{equation*}
the dirac delta transforms into $\delta' (-s)$. But since the dirac delta is even, then $\delta '(-s) = \delta '(s)$ and we would get
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{3} \left\langle \delta '(s) | e^{k(z,s)} \right\rangle, \quad k(z,s) = -z\left( \frac{2+s}{3} \right) -\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{2+s}{3} \right) ^{2}.
\end{equation*}
After that, it would be a matter of applying the properties of the generalized derivative so as to evaluate directly
\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{3} \left\langle \delta (s) | e^{k(z,s)}\frac{\partial k}{\partial s} \right\rangle &= -\frac{1}{3}\left\langle \delta (s) | \left( -\frac{1}{3}z - \frac{1}{9}(2+s) \right) e^{k(z,s)} \right\rangle. \\[1ex]
&= -\frac{1}{3} \left( -\frac{1}{3}z -\frac{2}{9} \right) e^{k(z,0)} \\[1ex]
&= \left( \frac{1}{9}z + \frac{2}{27} \right)e^{-2z/3}e^{-2/9}
\end{align*}
This is **my** result. I thought it'd be a good idea to check with WolframAlpha just to verify, but their result is
\begin{equation*}
\left( \frac{1}{3}z + \frac{2}{9} \right) e^{-2z/3}e^{-2/9}
\end{equation*}
And I have no clue how they get their result. I've been banging my head for hours and can't find the mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta'$ is odd not even.

Let $$T(x) = \delta(2-3x)= \frac13 \delta(2/3-x)=\frac13 \delta(x-2/3),\qquad T'(x) = -3 \delta'(2-3x)$$  thus $$\langle \delta'(2-3x),\varphi(x) \rangle = -\frac13\langle T'(x),\varphi(x) \rangle=\frac13\langle T(x),\varphi'(x) \rangle\\=\frac19\langle\delta(x-2/3) ,\varphi'(x)\rangle=\frac19 \varphi'(2/3)$$
Finally $$\langle e^{-zx}\delta'(2-3x), e^{-x^2/2} \rangle=\langle \delta'(2-3x), e^{-zx}e^{-x^2/2} \rangle$$

Comment: Oh boy, I totally forgot about it being **odd**. This is a step forward, but this yields the WolframAlpha result with the wrong sign.